# How do I remove all unnecessary whitespace from a string?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I pull some text from a website and save it in an NSString, and display it back to the user, but I want it in one clear line, one word after another word, with absolutely zero line-breaks or unnecessary whitespace or tabs.

Take the following image:

[image]

Body has all this spacing in it that I don't want. I do want spaces between words (so I want "This is a sentence", NOT "Thisisasentence") but all that spacing is really making the output ugly. How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regular expressions help a lot here:

```
NSString *tooManySpaces = @"   Too\tmany    spaces \n and on   several   \nlines, at that";
NSString *cleaned = [tooManySpaces stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"\\s+"
                                                             withString: @" "
                                                                options: NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                                                  range: NSMakeRange(0, tooManySpaces.length)];
```

The `\s` pattern covers whitespace, i.e. space, tab and newline. If that is too much, you can specify those that you need , like this: `[ \t]+` to cover space and tab characters.

In order to remove any excess whitespace at the beginning and the end, you also need to trim the string (either before or after applying the regex substitution):

```
cleaned = [cleaned stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: Will that not remove spaces between words as well?

Comment: @DougSmith Not sure exactly what you mean - it will reduce any white space sequence to one single space - i.e., leave a single space between all words that already had space between them. That was how I read your question. Notice that it replaces the sequence with a one-space string.

Comment: I forgot about that method. This is much easier than my approach. Though my solution is much more efficient if multiple strings need to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression to replace the pattern `@"  +"` (space space plus) with `@" "` (space).

In other words, this will replace all occurrences of two or more spaces with a single space.

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"  +" options:0 error:&error];
NSString *someString = ...; // some string with lots of spaces
NSString *newString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:someString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, someString.length) withTemplate:@" "];
```

Comment: I already have this: `NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(&lt;.*?&gt;|\\n|\\t|&.*?;)"` but it doesn't seem to catch them. (It removes all HTML formatting too.)

Comment: That's a whole different issue. Your question was about removing extra spaces. Now you talk about some other regular expression that is giving you issues.